# I am trying to add data to a column in an existing row using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to add data into a column called address for a certain user. This is the code I am using;

```
 Insert into register(address) values("Cork") where userId=1;
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing ?

Comment: This `INSERT` query does not modify a existing row, it creates a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Update register set address='Cork' where userId=1
```

If something already exists, we use Update.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need `update` statement rather than `insert` :

```
update register
     set address = 'Cork'
where userId = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **append** a value, use the `CONCAT()` function, as in:

```
update register set address = concat(address, 'Cork') where userId = 1;
```

If you want to **set** the value, then a simple `UPDATE` will do, as in:

```
update register set address = 'Cork' where userId = 1;
```